# Angularjs parse json array of dictionaries

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, parsing

I am using angular's fromJson function to parse a json string. 
If the json is a simple array, like "[1, 2]", then the following code is working. But what I need is an array of dictionaries.

```
    var str = "[{'title':'hi'}, {'title':'what'}]"
    alert(str) //1
    alert(str.length) //2
    var j = angular.fromJson(str)
    alert(j) //3
    alert(j.length) //4
```

1 and 2 are alerted out, which are string representation
3 and 4 are not, which means fromJson has error.

Note: It has nothing to do with JSON.parse or $._parseJSON functions. I need to use the angular one for some reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you have invalid JSON. For json to be valid you must wrap properties in double quotes not single quotes. So try using

```
  '[{"title":"hi"}, {"title":"what"}]'
```

See [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON#Description)

> Property names must be double-quoted strings; trailing commas are forbidden.